# Vector sequence in $l^2$ is Cauchy

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that the sequence of vectors in $l^2$ $ \{ v^{(n)} \} _{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ which is defined as $ \underline v^{(n)}:= \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{-k \alpha} \underline e^{(k)}$ ,   $\alpha > 0$

where $\{ \underline e^{(n)} \} _{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ denotes the canonical basis for $l^2$  is Cauchy

I started this way :
$|| \underline v ^{(m)} - \underline v ^{(n)}|| = 
 || \sum_{k=1}^{m} e^{-k \alpha} \underline e^{(k)} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{-k \alpha} \underline e^{(k)}||_2 =  \\|| \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} e^{-k \alpha} \underline e^{(k)} ||_2$

now this must be bounded cause it's in $l^2$ but I don't know how to come forward. $\\$

The second part is to evaluate the norm of the given sequence vector as n goes to infinity. This sequence must converge since the $l^2$ space is complete but I think I must prove that without using this fact.

I am sorry for the long question and I will be thankful for any tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from what you did: We have due to triangle inequality:
$$\|v^{(m)}-v^{(n)}\|=\|\sum_{k=n+1}^me^{-k\alpha}e^{(k)}\|\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^me^{-k\alpha},\;\;\;(*) $$

Now the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{e^{k\alpha}}$ converge (see the next computation) and since it converges it is Cauchy, and this shows that the estimate in $(*)$ becomes small (take $\varepsilon>0$ find $N$ such that for $n,m$ greater than $N$ the partial sums are close..)

The norm of $v^{(n)}$ can by computed via Parseval's identity: we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|v^{(n)}\|^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-2k\alpha}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(e^{-2\alpha})^k=\frac{e^{-2\alpha}}{1-e^{-2\alpha}} $$
so taking the square root gives the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't imagine it is this simple :)